# Symfony 2: How do I check if a user is not logged in inside a template?

Tags: symfony, authentication, twig, symfony-2.1

In Symfony 2 templates (using Twig), how can I effectively check whether a user is not logged in?

I don't want to use `ROLE` checks. I want a straightforward way to check if a user is not logged in.

I'm aware that comparing `app.user.username` with `anon` works, but that just doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can check if app.user is set.

```
 {% if app.user %}
    # user is logged in
 {% else %}
    # user is not logged in
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to check if the user is NOT logged in you can use: `{% if not app.user %}`

Comment: Use `{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}` instead. See Symfony2 doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object. Also available for Silex : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#checking-user-roles

Comment: @Ronan ```{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}``` will only return true if the user has authenticated in the current session. It will return false if the user authenticated via a remember me cookie. Using ```{% if app.user %}``` is correct, if one wants to return true regardless of when the user authenticated.

Comment: @Ronan, that doesn't work as it results in the following error:

No Authentication Provider found for token of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken".

Comment: `{% if app.security.token is null or app.security.token.user == 'anon.' %}` that's how I got it working for me

Answer (score 103):

Although the current answer answers the OP's question, I would like to add more details.

*I understand the OP did not want to check roles, but I am including them so other SO users can copy and paste from this in the future. - everytime I google this, I end up here!*

Symfony Doc Sources:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

---

### Check if any user logged in (regardless of role)

As answered, you can use `app.user` to check if *any* user is logged in.

```
{% if app.user %}
    # user is logged in (any and all users, regardless of ROLE_*)
{% elseif not app.user %}
    # user is not logged in (note the `not` in the `elseif` statement)
{% endif %}
```

---

### Checking authentication status

You can use the `is_granted()` method to check for `ROLES`, (The below are all roles assigned by symfony, You may also have you own roles *(more below)*)

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    # This user entered their credentials THIS session
{% elseif is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
    # User logged in via a cookie (ie: Auth again before doing sensitive things)
{% elseif is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') %}
    # This is a `guest` or anonymous user
{% endif %}
```

*from the docs:*

> IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY - automatically assigned to a user who is
>   in a firewall protected part of the site but who has not actually
>   logged in. This is only possible if anonymous access has been allowed.
>
> IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED - automatically assigned to a user who was
>   authenticated via a remember me cookie.
>
> IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY - automatically assigned to a user that has
>   provided their login details during the current session.

---

### Checking Roles

You can also use `is_granted()` to check for roles.
Assuming we have 3 roles (`ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, `ROLE_ADMIN`, & `ROLE_USER`)

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') -%}
    # You're `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') -%}
    # You're `ROLE_ADMIN`
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') -%}
    # You're `ROLE_USER`
{% else %}
    # You're a `nobody` ;P
{%- endif %}
```

---

### Doing the above inside a controller

View the following answer: [How to check if an user is logged in Symfony2 inside a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller/31866186#31866186)

Comment: I'm just curious... what `-%}` and `{%-` stands for ? why not `%}` and `{%` ?

Comment: The `-` removes all trailing whitespace so that it's more readable in the browser source source. More info here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control

Comment: Forgive me for bringing this old question to live again, but I think I read somewhere that app.user will not be null for anonymous users, isn't that correct? Wouldn't that mean that check for app.user is not sufficient?

Comment: @Anil http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating/app_variable.html second parameter described is `app.user`, going like that `The value stored in this variable can be a UserInterface object, any other object which implements a __toString() method or even a regular string.`. I don't remember where I read that app.user returns "anon." string unfortunately and under what circumstances.

Comment: @user1970395 The first line in the docs read `The representation of the current user or null if there is none.`, so it will be null. A third party bundle  could return a string if it's custom `UserInterface` implementation has a `__toString()` method which is called when anonymous.