# How to check if a user is logged in Symfony2 inside a controller?

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660764/in-symfony-2-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-not-logged-in-inside-a-template) how to check the login status of a user by inside a twig template for a Symfony2-based website.
However, I need to know how to check if the user is logged in from inside a controller. I was quite sure the the following code was right:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

but it always return something, e.g. a logged user or an anonymous user.

Any idea?

Comment: can't you could check if $user != "anon."?

Comment: Well, I was looking for something more "secure". Isn't another way, i.e. some function to call?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

**Warning**: Checking for `'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'` alone will return false if the user has logged in using "Remember me" functionality.

According to Symfony 2 documentation, there are 3 possibilities:

> **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** - automatically assigned to a user who is
>   in a firewall protected part of the site but who has not actually
>   logged in. This is only possible if anonymous access has been allowed.
>
> **IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED** - automatically assigned to a user who was
>   authenticated via a remember me cookie.
>
> **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY** - automatically assigned to a user that has
>   provided their login details during the current session.

Those roles represent three levels of authentication:

> If you have the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` role, then you also have
>   the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role. If you have the
>   `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` role, then you also have the other two roles.
>   In other words, these roles represent three levels of increasing
>   "strength" of authentication.

I ran into an issue where users of our system that had used "Remember Me" functionality were being treated as if they had not logged in at all on pages that only checked for `'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'`.

The answer then is to require them to re-login if they are not authenticated fully, or to check for the remembered role:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
    // authenticated REMEMBERED, FULLY will imply REMEMBERED (NON anonymous)
}
```

Hopefully, this will save someone out there from making the same mistake I made.  I used this very post as a reference when looking up how to check if someone was logged in or not on Symfony 2.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-re-authenticate-before-accessing-certain-resources

Comment: Actually, you could just use `$securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')`, since the roles are hierarchical. So having `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` implies that the user also has `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`.

Comment: Not true.  IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED returns true only when the user uses "Remember me" functionality.  Having IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY does imply IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, but not the other way around.

Comment: Right. If `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` also guarantees that a user has `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, then you only ever need to check for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`.

Comment: Think of them like subclasses. If `B` is a subclass of `A`, then anything that is a subclass of `B` will also be a subclass of `A`. Thus, checking that a class is a subclass of both `A` and `B` is redundant.

Comment: I read you answer and I decided to put it as selected answer.

Comment: How is this handled when you have different ROLES. For example, I have a ROLE_USER and a ROLE_ADMIN, that is required for certain areas of the site, I would like to allow both of these types of users access to their respective areas with the IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED level. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Comment: _"Checking for 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' alone will return false if the user has logged in using "Remember me" functionality"_

This is not the case in Symfony 3 (I'm using 3.3.5). In other words, `- { path: ^/some-path, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }` is accessible for users whether they check 'Remember me' or not.

Comment: I don't like redundancy, duplicate code is bad m'kay. BUT sometimes it is not a bad thing to be explicit. Personally I would check for both simply because the code would be easier to understand for my future self and others. Even though it is true, the inheritance in this case is not logical, and therefore might be confusing in the future.

Answer (score 56):

## SecurityContext will be deprecated in `Symfony 3.0`

Prior to `Symfony 2.6` you would use `SecurityContext`.
`SecurityContext` will be deprecated in `Symfony 3.0` in favour of the [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker).

**For `Symfony 2.6+` & `Symfony 3.0` use [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker).**

---

## Symfony 2.6 (and below)

```
// Get our Security Context Object - [deprecated in 3.0]
$security_context = $this->get('security.context');
# e.g: $security_context->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

// Get our Token (representing the currently logged in user)
$security_token = $security_context->getToken();
# e.g: $security_token->getUser();
# e.g: $security_token->isAuthenticated();
# [Careful]             ^ "Anonymous users are technically authenticated"

// Get our user from that security_token
$user = $security_token->getUser();
# e.g: $user->getEmail(); $user->isSuperAdmin(); $user->hasRole();

// Check for Roles on the $security_context
$isRoleAdmin = $security_context->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
# e.g: (bool) true/false
```

---

## Symfony 3.0+ (and from Symfony 2.6+)

`security.context` becomes `security.authorization_checker`.
We now get our token from `security.token_storage` instead of the `security.context`

```
// [New 3.0] Get our "authorization_checker" Object
$auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
# e.g: $auth_checker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

// Get our Token (representing the currently logged in user)
// [New 3.0] Get the `token_storage` object (instead of calling upon `security.context`)
$token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
# e.g: $token->getUser();
# e.g: $token->isAuthenticated();
# [Careful]            ^ "Anonymous users are technically authenticated"

// Get our user from that token
$user = $token->getUser();
# e.g (w/ FOSUserBundle): $user->getEmail(); $user->isSuperAdmin(); $user->hasRole();

// [New 3.0] Check for Roles on the $auth_checker
$isRoleAdmin = $auth_checker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
// e.g: (bool) true/false
```

---

Read more here in the docs: [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker)
How to do this in twig?: [Symfony 2: How do I check if a user is not logged in inside a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660764/symfony-2-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-not-logged-in-inside-a-template/23612913#23612913)

Comment: From inside symfony `Controller` you can just write `$this->isGranted($role, $obj, $errMsg)`. The `denyAccessUnlessGranted()` function and the `isGranted()` functions are both just shortcuts to call `isGranted()` on the `security.authorization_checker` service.

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```
if( $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ){
    // authenticated (NON anonymous)
}
```

Further information:

> "Anonymous users are technically authenticated, meaning that the
>   isAuthenticated() method of an anonymous user object will return true.
>   To check if your user is actually authenticated, check for the
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY role."

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: Yes! It works... thank you so much! However, do you think that the $user != "anon." is secure enough? My fear is that a new release could change the value returned by an anonymous user! Isn't it possible?

Comment: Well.. since there is this solution provided by Symfony, I'd suggest you to use this one (isGranted). I don't think they're going to change the behaviour of such a basic feature as the security component. By the way, using isGranted is far more professional and clean than a simple string comparison.

Comment: Thanks again for the complete answer!

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Comment: You have requested a non-existent service "security.context".

Comment: security.context is deprecated

Answer (score 9):

To add to answer given by Anil, In **symfony3**, you can use `$this->getUser()` to determine if the user is logged in, a simple condition like `if(!$this->getUser()) {}` will do.

If you look at the source code which is available in base controller, it does the exact same thing defined by Anil.

Comment: The $this->getUser() approach is working just fine, just tested it in Symfony 5. Also, Suppose in controller you have $someVar = $this->getUser(); and pass it to twig. Then you can do somewhere inside body tag {{dump(someVar)}} or {% dump(someVar) %} and you will get either a null or the content of user object.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using security annotation from the `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle`, you can use a few expressions (that are defined in `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\ExpressionLanguageProvider`):

- `@Security("is_authenticated()")`: to check that the user is authed and not anonymous
- `@Security("is_anonymous()")`: to check if the current user is the anonymous user
- `@Security("is_fully_authenticated()")`: equivalent to `is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')`
- `@Security("is_remember_me()")`: equivalent to `is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')`

Answer (score 6):

If you using roles you could check for `ROLE_USER`
that is the solution i use:

```
if (TRUE === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

Comment: Assuming your app assigns `ROLE_USER` to everyone. Not all apps do.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practise to extend from a `baseController` and implement some base functions
implement a function to check if the user instance is null like this
if the user form the `Userinterface` then there is no user logged in

```
/**

*/
class BaseController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @return User

     */
    protected function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return parent::getUser();
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isUserLoggedIn(): bool
    {
        return $this->getUser() instanceof User;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. I am a beginner at Symfony but accessing $this->user() from a controller works perfectly.

Comment: Because I think it's actually not a good practice to do that like this. I prefer composition way more. What if another service wants to know if user is logged in. Also i don't know why ovewrite `getUser()` method. Wrong and useless annotations on top of it.