# How do I check for user role in symfony2 for urls not falling under patterns defined security.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a admin panel and I have defined a role for it `ROLE_ADMIN`. In my security.yml file I am using a pattern `^/admin/*` so every thing under /admin requires `ROLE_ADMIN`. Now in frontend of my app I need to check user role and if role is `ROLE_ADMIN` render one file and otherwise render another file. This url does not fall under the pattern defined in security.yml.

So how do I check whether the user is admin or a normal user on the homepage which does not fall under the pattern defined in security.yml ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Enable the firewall on the whole app using the `^/` pattern, permit anonymous access and use `access_control` to restrict access:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

---

As @itsmequinn suggested, use the `isGranted()` method of the security context:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_BRAND')) {
    // the user has the ROLE_BRAND role, so act accordingly
}
```

---

In **Symfony 2.6**, `security.context` has been split into two separate services. Hence you need to use the `security.authorization_checker` service to solve the problem:

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_BRAND')) {
    // the user has the ROLE_BRAND role, so act accordingly
}
```

Comment: The thing is I already had 2 roles defined one `ROLE_ADMIN` for pattern example.com/admin/* and other `ROLE_BRAND` for example.com/brand/dashboard/* with separate login page. Now I want to check on page example.com whether it is an anonymous user or a guy who has a role `ROLE_BRAND`

Comment: @Elnur Abdurrakhimov forgotten to close if statement. It should be
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_BRAND')) {
//
}

Comment: This is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. See answer by @Anil below.

Comment: AFAIK, the PHP community is probably the only one where people prefer creating a separate answer instead of just updating a perfectly valid and accepted but outdated answer. Meh.

Answer (score 20):

## SecurityContext will be deprecated in `Symfony 3.0`

Prior to `Symfony 2.6` you would use `SecurityContext`.
`SecurityContext` will be deprecated in `Symfony 3.0` in favour of the [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker).

**For `Symfony 2.6+` & `Symfony 3.0` use [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker).**

---

## Symfony 2.5 (and below)

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    # User is a ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

---

## Symfony 2.6 (and above)

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    # User is a ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

---

Similar Question: [How to check if an user is logged in Symfony2 inside a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller/31866186#31866186)

Read more the docs here: [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker)

Answer (score 5):

Are you in the controller for the page? If so, use the `isGranted` method of the security context: [Access Controls for Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-controllers)

Comment: Actually there is no firewall configured for that url so security context contains no authentication. How do i configure firewall for a particular URL so that it can be viewed by everyone and if the role is `ROLE_ADMIN` I give some extra features on my home page

Comment: Elnur's answer below will help you with that. You need to enable a firewall on all paths but allow anonymous users to access `^/` and authenticated users to access whatever it is you want to lock down. After that you can use `isGranted`. If the user is anonymous, they will match `isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')`. Otherwise, they will match for whatever roles they are granted.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution for this are annotations. Instead of this:

```
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
       # User is a ROLE_ADMIN
    }
```

.. try use this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
```

.. or :

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Security("is_granted('POST_ADD', post)")
 */
public function addAction(Post $post){...}
```

You can read more about [Security annotations here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html). Annotations are best practice in Symfony 2 look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#authorization-i-e-denying-access) Enjoy!

Comment: Ok but is there a way to redirect if you don't meet the role you need to access the page?

Comment: everything you can set up in access control

Answer (score 1):

In **Symfony 4 and above** you should use code like below,
instead of using services like $this->get('security.authorization_checker'):

```
$hasAccess = $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

[Symfony security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles)