# How to display layout content in Twig template based on a view

Tags: templates, symfony, layout, view, twig

I have some content in my layout that are not supposed to be displayed in some pages.

E.g.: When a user is registering for the site my default frontpage sidebar should not be displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
           <div id="sidebar">
               {% block sidebar %}
                   {% render "/layout/sidebar" %}
               {% endblock %}
               {% block content %}{% endblock %}
           </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2011 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code:

```
 {% block sidebar %}
```

should display some advertising instead!

So:

Something like:

```
{% if SOMEVIEW == TRUE %}
    {% block sidebar %}
{% else %}
    {% block advertising %}
{% endif %}
```

What expression could I use in my IF to accomplish that job?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can look at 
[How to check if an user is logged in Symfony2 inside a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller)

and http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates

In the view you can use `{{ is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') }}` to check if a user is logged in.

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross to the solution here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/core.html#twig:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_template').get('name')
```

will return the route name so that I can handle it inside my twig files.