# Redirect works incorrectly

Tags: security, symfony, redirect

I try to reidrect user to login page if he not authenticated, but redirect work in both cases. Here is my code:

```
 $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {

   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));

} else {

$currentUser = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getProfile()->getId();
$pathToImages = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web';
$userCars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VputiUserBundle:Car')
                 ->findBy(array('profile' => $currentUser));

 return $this->render('VputiUserBundle:Car:index.html.twig', 
                array('userCars' =>$userCars,
                     'pathToImages' => $pathToImages));
```

}

Where I am wrong? Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every user is granted `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, so that will always resolve to `true`. What you want is to check that the user wasn't granted `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, like this:

```
if ( ! $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {

   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));

} else {
   ...
}
```

I recommend reading [this fantastic answer about roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984413/3052486) for more information.

Anyway, **in this case you don't need to do that**. By default, when you send someone to a page that's behind a firewall it will automatically redirect them to the `login` page if they're not authenticated.

Comment: so if any user has `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` hat reason to use it?

Comment: It's the base level of the hierarchy. You use it to say things like `path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, i.e., anyone can access that path.

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony2 are three level of authentication

- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

If a user have `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` role has also `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.
If a user have `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` role has also `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`

So, everytime you check, you will pass that control. Try to "invert" logic: check for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and render the page, redirect otherwise

Working code for your case

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    $currentUser = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getProfile()->getId();
    $pathToImages = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web';
    $userCars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VputiUserBundle:Car')
                       ->findBy(array('profile' => $currentUser));

    return $this->render('VputiUserBundle:Car:index.html.twig', 
                    array('userCars' =>$userCars,
                          'pathToImages' => $pathToImages));
} else {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
}
```

Comment: That won't work for users who were authenticated via a remember me cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that all users who have been authenticated at all, either anonymously, via the "remember me" function, or fully using a username and password, have the "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" role; they stack.  So your test always returns true, and the user is always redirected.

In this case, it may be better to do the test the other way around - redirect if the user *doesn't* have "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" or "IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED".

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984413/84649