# Redirect anonymous user to /login page

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

So, I'm using FOSUserBundle and symfony 2.8 project

if there is any way to redirect anonymous user to /login page, if he required / page?

Answer (score 1):

Use a firewall to protect `/`:

```yaml
# app/config/security.yml

security:

    firewalls:
        app:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

More details in the [FOSUserBundle docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-4-configure-your-application-s-security-yml).

Comment: that is how my security.yml looks like now, but it isn't working for me, I don't know why

Comment: Did you follow the FOSUserBundle guide? Activated the bundle etc

Comment: I suspect conflicting rules within your `security.yml`. Feel free to post your full file here: https://gist.github.com

Answer (score 0):

First, check [if the user is authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller). Then, use an if condition to redirect the user.

**Full example of your index:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $context = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
    if (!($context->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))) {
        $this->redirect('http://yourpage.com/login');
    } else {
      //Do your other stuff here
    }
}
```