# How to check if a user is authenticated in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Started learning Symfony and ran into a problem. How to check if a user is logged into the site and how to get it? For example, in Laravel it is done something like this: `Auth::check()` or get user id: `Auth::user()->id`. I can use about the same thing in the blade template engine.

How can I do the same in Symfony? How can I check a user and get his object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller

Check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` class to get user object.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class EditController extend AbstractController
{
    function create(Request $request, Security $security)
    {
        $user = $security->getUser();
    }
}
```