# Verify if user is authenticated in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I tried to create a simple login application in symfony2 and I don't understand a thing.
My routing file :

```
shop_show_login_page:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage }

shop_login_user:
path: /loginUser
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginCheck }
```

My controller with this 2 methods :

```
public function loginPageAction(){
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig');
}
public function loginCheckAction(Request $request){
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    $login    = $request->request->get('username');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Customer');
    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('customer_login'=> $login, 'customer_password'=> $password));
    if($user){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('shop_desktop_homepage'));
    }else{
        return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig',array('message_failed' => 'Error'));
    }
}
```

My form in view :

```
 <form action="{{ path('shop_login_user') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Autentificare</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This system on login work fine but the problem is in the layout.html.twig:

```
{% if app.user %}
     <p>Test</p>
{% elseif not app.user %}
     <span><a href="{{ path('shop_show_login_page') }}" style="color: #ffffff;">Login / Register</a></span>
{% endif %}
```

My security.yml:

```
security:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: shop_login_user
            login_path: shop_show_login_page
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

So I want to see in the page "Test" if user is authentificated with succes and Login/Register if authentification failed. I tried with "if app.user" but I don't understand the principle.

Comment: Wich version of Symfony are you using??? The question have multiple version tags (2.1 and 2.3)

Comment: duplicated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660764/symfony-2-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-not-logged-in-inside-a-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to check if user is authenticated.

One would be with `app.user` as you tried, like this:

```
{% if app.user is not empty %}
```

That will check if your user object is populated with data.

You can also use [is_granted()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates).

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

*- Update -*

The error you provided in comments could be caused by the fact that you try to use the `is_granted` function when you're not behind a firewall. If that's the case you can first check if there is a security token before calling for `is_granted` with `if app.security.token is not empty`. Would you include your security.yml file?

*- Update -*

Your security file is required to be set up properly in order for your authentication to work. The default behaviour is set to give you a starting point, but you have to configure your firewall. Take a look and read carefully the chapter about [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) in Symfony.

Comment: Does the debug toolbar shows that you are logged after you submit your form?

Comment: I get the error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL."

Comment: @Gigel, added a little bit more info.

Comment: I added the security.yml, I don't change them, it's default

Comment: @Gigel, You need to configure the security as well. I added link to the chapter that you should read.

Comment: I edited my security.yml, If I acces home page I'm redirecting to /login