# Drupal 8 conditional syntax

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm looking for the proper syntax with a Drupal 8 conditional display of a link. I've been reading the twig documentation, and it's a significant jump from the PHP templating days so it's slow going. I need to conditionally display a link within the footer of a view.

In the past, this would be straightforward, i.e:

```
<?php global $user;?>
<?php if (user_access('administer nodes')):?>
<div class="foo"><a href="/">Shorthand link for admins</a></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Getting this to work in Twig has been difficult as I'm unfamiliar with the syntax. Do I need to declare global user in some capacity? From this link here, [Symfony 2: How do I check if a user is not logged in inside a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660764/symfony-2-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-not-logged-in-inside-a-template), it seems that all I'd need to do is:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') -%}
<div class="foo"><a href="/">Shorthand link for admins</a></div>
{% endif %}
```

But I get an error when trying to submit that. Is ROLE_ADMIN not defined? How do I get the Symphony? (correct?) roles as defined within the D8 installation? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I also checked the syntax from this link here, http://drupal8notes.github.io/how-to-check-for-user-access-in-drupal-8/, but unsure how to include this in the view footer. The input format I'm testing with accepts PHP.

Comment: What error do you get?  [Edit] your question to include that detail

Comment: I also depend on the template you are trying to modify. You may not have the user object in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check a specific permission try

```
{% if user.hasPermission('administer nodes') %}
  <div class="foo"><a href="/">Shorthand link for admins</a></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to check the current user is administer in TWIG file , you can use

```
{% if is_admin %}
  <div class="foo"><a href="/">Shorthand link for admins</a></div>
{% endif %}
```